# Why is my LSTM prediction not working right

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, predict

i have a problem on predicting a time series data using lstm neuron network.

i finally get the code to run but it didn't run as expected. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

with open('lalal.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    l = [row for row in reader]
    l_hoandoi = [list(x) for x in zip(*l)]
    #print(l_hoandoi)
    #print(len(l))
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    X_train.append(i)
    y_train.append(float(l_hoandoi[0][i]))

X_train =np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)


#plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show()

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
#print([y_train,X_train])

scaler.fit(y_train.reshape([-1,1]))
a=y_train.reshape([-1,1])
scaled_train= scaler.transform(a)

n_input = 12
n_feature = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=n_input,batch_size=1)

X,y = generator[1]
print(f'given the Array: \n{X.flatten()}')
print(f'predict this y:\n {y}')

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_feature)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
#model.summary()
model.fit(generator,epochs=50)

test_predictions = []
first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-n_input:]
current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape(1,n_input,n_feature)

for i in range(1,500):
    current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]
    test_predictions.append(current_pred)
    current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:,1:,:],[[current_pred]],axis=1)

print(test_predictions)
true_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions)
```

and here is the link to lalal.csv:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1omZhiAdWrKtGNfuwQKgkbCQ1dam3Ncuc/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [mre]. Please do not post links to code and reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text